# How to show different web content depending on <c:if> with variable in a jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, if-statement

I'm trying to show different web content in a jsp page depending on the user's access level (admin or user). 
I have a session with the attribute "access" that is = 1 if the user is an admin, otherwise = 2; this works because I can see the access level in the page by

`<%out.print("access = "+session.getAttribute("access"));%>`

I tried `<c:if>` using var TEST in this way:

```
<%String test = session.getAttribute("access").toString();%>
<%out.print("test = "+test);%>
```

With

```
  <c:if test="1">
          <p>Content Admin (table for example)</p>
    <c:else>
    .....
    </c:else>
</c:if>
```

it never shows what you put in If statement on the page.
Is there a solution for that? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should really read the documentation of the things you're using. There is no c:else tag. That doesn't exist, and has never existed.

```
<c:if test="1">
```

will test if `1` is true. You don't want that. You want to test if `access` is equal to 1.

So you need

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${access == 1}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: This is the body with your solution

<body>
<%out.print("access = "+session.getAttribute("access"));%>
<%String accesso = session.getAttribute("access").toString();%>
<%out.print("access = "+access);%>
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${access == 2}">
<select>
....
</select>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <a href='logout.jsp'>LogOut</a>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

but it still doesn't show the content supposed to be shown.
It shows nothing.

Comment: Your question says the attribute is named access. Your comment says it's named u_accesso. Make up your mind. It can't show nothing. Eother it show what is in the c:when, or it shows what is inside the c:otherwise.